# AS3. offset and dynamic height in for loop

Tags: actionscript-3

Im working on this for loop where i want to offset all objects by its own height (dynamic) and an offset value.

My code currently looks like this. Now it only offsets correct if all elements has the same height. What i want is to be able to offset them based on a dynamic height.

The `SpeechBubble` is just a movieclip. When i trace its height in the loop i get the correct values. I can't just figure out how to calculate and set the correct offset.

Anyone?

```
        for (var i:int = 0; i< _conversation.length; i++) {

            var sp = new SpeechBubble(
                _conversation[i].text,
                _conversation[i].pos,
                _bannerWidth,
                _color
            );

            _messages.push(sp);
            _messages[i].y += i * _messages[i].height;
            _container.addChild(_messages[i]);
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: `_messages` is just holding a bunch of MovieClips `(SpeechBubble)`. Its those ones i want to offset by their height + some padding. Thing is that the heigh is different on everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like that:

Variables declared before your loop:

```
var deltaY:int = 0;
const PADDING:int = 10;
```

The last three lines of your loop would be:

```
_messages[i].y = deltaY;
deltaY += _messages[i].height + padding;
_container.addChild(_messages[i]);
```

At the beginning deltaY is equal to 0, then equal to the sum of the cumulative heights. A padding variable has been added.